# Off screen absolute positioned Div causing horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css, safari

**EDIT/UPDATE:** 7th June 2019

I've determined this is a bug in Safari, as the CSS works perfectly in all other browser. For anyone who finds this, if you're creating a sliding menu (which slides offscreen to the right of the viewport), as of Safari 12.1.1, adding overflow-x to the body tag will *not* work (it does work on Chrome, Firefox etc) - this means that when your menu div is positioned offscreen to the right, the user can scroll horizontally and see the menu.

I've found a (sort of) workaround is to give the parent container of the menu dive a position:fixed attribute - this obviously only works if you intend for your header to be fixed.

**Original Question**

I'm building a simple header with a menu that slides from right to left when the menu button is pressed. However, when I position the menu div offscreen (left: 100%), on Safari, I can scroll horizontally right to see the menu div. (No scroll bars appear, but I can scroll right via the Mouse)

If I set `overflow-x:hidden` on the header, then it hides the offscreen div, but also won't show it if you set the `left:0` (ie. `overflow-x` seems to be hiding x and y directions).

Even more perplexing, if I change the header to `position:fixed`, then it works and you can't scroll right to see the offscreen menu div.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #CCC;
  position: relative;
}

.slideMenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #666;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  Header ---> Scroll to Right
  <div class="slideMenu">
    Menu is visible offscreen- :(
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/ar7qyfgt/

Comment: It works, just set `left` to 0 instead of 0%. See here - https://jsfiddle.net/dv8m71z4/6/

Comment: @ChristopherBennett - Yes, I know. The question is about when the Menu div is moved offscreen (ie Menu is in a closed state). On Safari, it still allows you to scroll horizontally to view an "off screen" item. I've updated my original question as I believe this to be a bug in Safari.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same issue in my Safari(Version 12.1.1) when I set my div to position: absolute and right: -15rem;

To fix it, I added a  to include all elements within  and have the CSS like this:

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a similar issue with Safari. Solution that appears to be working is to apply `overflow-x: hidden;` to the `html` AND `body` tags.

Adding to body resolved issue in all browsers expect Safari. Applying it to both seems to do the trick with Safari while still supporting the other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

What you currently have works, you just need to set `overflow-x:hidden` on the `body` instead of the `.header`

Comment: That works in the jsfiddle, but the exact same code in my HTML file doesn't work in Safari! Here's the code:

https://pastebin.com/zz7c4Ehd

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to accomplish? This?: 
[image]

JSFiddle: `(https://jsfiddle.net/pzeqfb51/)`

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  Header ---> Scroll to Right
  <div class="slideMenu">
    Menu is visible offscreen- :(
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #CCC;
  position: relative;
}

.slideMenu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #666;
}

div {
  display:inline-block;
}
```